# Wordpress pages and template query

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possibe in wordpress to have only one template for pages and have different layout or design per page?
I only know that if the page requires to have a different design, i will have to create a page template for it or simply creating a file with wordpress rules like for example 'page-pageslug.php' to be able to create a different layout for a specific page. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Why you added javascript in your tag?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use and you can make different layouts using

```
 if(is_page(pageid){
    //condition
    })
```